# Insert MySQL table column array into new MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php form that gets dumped into a MySQL table. I create an array that is populated from a Product table using php.

Queries the table to get the values for the array - works fine.

```
 <?php 
 function getProducts ($id)
 {
    $sql =("SELECT * FROM products where products.CAT_ID = $id AND DISABLED ='NO'");
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    if ($result > 0)
    {
    $products = array();
    $x=0;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $products[$x]= $row;
        $x += 1;
    }
    return $products;
    }
    else return false;  
}
function newProd(){
global $products;
}
?>
```

Then I use the above array to create labels in a javascript accordion. Next to the labels -are select boxes. (Removed unnecessary page elements.. ) Html/php form below that displays the above array.

```
<?php include('includes/query.php');?>
```

Inventory

```
<body onload="toggleField()">

        <div id="container" class="container_16">
        <form name="form1" id="form1" action="insert.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="height: inherit">
            <div id="Info" class="grid_16"> 
                <fieldset>
                    <label id="Label1">
                        <span class="Labels">Store Information</span> <br>
                    </label>
                    <div>
                    <label for="name"> 
                        <span class="Labels"> Name :</span> </label> 
            <input id="name" name="name" type="text">  
                    </div>  
          </fieldset>
            </div>
            <hr id="SpacePadding">
            <hr class="SpacePadding">
            <div class="clear"></div>
                <!-- Start of the Accordion Container-->
                <!-- Start array, make sure Category Array isn't false -->
                <?php if($categoryArray !=false):?>
                    <!-- create the variables for modulus -->
                    <!-- Start the foreach loop for the category Array -->
                    <?php $cataCounter = 0; ?>
                    <?php $closeSection = false; ?>
                    <?php foreach($categoryArray as $row):?>
                        <?php if($cataCounter % 2 == 0): ?>
                            <div class="push_1 grid_8">
                            <?php $closeSection = false; ?>
                        <?php else: ?>
                            <div class="grid_8">
                            <?php $closeSection = true; ?>
                        <?php endif; ?><!-- insert modulus-->
                                <div class="AccordionTitle"><?php echo $row['CATEGORY_NAME'];?></div>
                                <div class="AccordionContent">
                                    <table>
                                        <?php foreach(getProducts($row['CAT_ID']) as $row):?>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th class="boldLabels"><?php echo $row['PRODUCT_NAME'];?>
                                            <span class="label"></span></th>
                                            <th><span class="Labels">Count:</span></th>
                                            <td>
                                                <select name="selCount[]" onChange="toggleField(this.value);" class="Listbox">
                                                    <option value="Select">Select One</option>
                                                    <option value="0">0</option>
                                                    <option value="1">1</option>
                                                    <option value="2">2</option>
                                                    <option value="3">3</option>
                                                    <option value="4">4</option>
                                                    <option value="5">5</option>
                                                    <option value="6">6</option>
                                                    <option value="7">7</option>
                                                    <option value="8">8</option>
                                                    <option value="9">9</option>
                                                    <option value="10">10</option>
                                                    <option value="Other">Other(Specify)</option>
                                                </select>
                                                <input type="text" name="otherCount[]" class ="Listbox" style="display: none;">
                                            </td>
                                            <td><span class="Labels">Need:</span></td>  
                                            <td>
                                                <select name="selNeed[]" onChange="toggleField2(this.value);" class="Listbox">
                                                    <option value="Select">Select One</option>
                                                    <option value="0">0</option>
                                                    <option value="1">1</option>
                                                    <option value="2">2</option>
                                                    <option value="3">3</option>
                                                    <option value="4">4</option>
                                                    <option value="5">5</option>
                                                    <option value="6">6</option>
                                                    <option value="7">7</option>
                                                    <option value="8">8</option>
                                                    <option value="9">9</option>
                                                    <option value="10">10</option>
                                                    <option value="Other">Other(Specify)</option>
                                                </select>
                                                <input type="text" name="otherNeed[]" class ="Listbox" style="display: none;">
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <?php endforeach;?>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <?php if($closeSection): ?>
                                <div class="clear"></div>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php $cataCounter += 1; ?>
                    <?php endforeach;?>
            <?php endif;?>

        <input name="Submit" type="submit" value="submit">
        </div>
        </form>
        <br>
    </div>
        <footer>
        <div align="center">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Daily Inventory Counts</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact System Admin</a></li>   
            </ul>
        </div>
    </footer>
</body>
```

When submitted, I want the Product_Name to go inside a new table with the correlating select option.
(i took out the database connection info out.)

```
    <?php
//Assign array
$SelCount = $_POST['selCount'];
$SelNeed = $_POST['selNeed'];
$otherNeed = $_POST['otherNeed'];
$otherCount = $_POST['otherCount'];

$limit = count($SelCount);

for($i=0;$i<$limit;$i++) {
    $SelCount[$i] = mysql_real_escape_string($SelCount[$i]);
    $SelNeed[$i] = mysql_real_escape_string($SelNeed[$i]);
    $otherNeed[$i] = mysql_real_escape_string($otherNeed[$i]);
    $otherCount[$i] = mysql_real_escape_string($otherCount[$i]);    

if  (($SelCount[$i]) !="Select" ) {
$sql = ("INSERT INTO inventory ( STORE_ID, REQUESTOR, ITEM_COUNT, ITEM_NEED, NEED_COUNT, OTHER_COUNT) 
VALUES ('$_POST[store]', '$_POST[name]', '".$SelCount[$i]."', '".$SelNeed[$i]."', '".$otherNeed[$i]."', '".$otherCount[$i]."')");

    if(mysql_query($sql ,$db)) 
        echo "$i successfully inserted.<br/>";
        else 
        echo "$i encountered an error. <br/>";

    } 
}

?>
```

Comment: You have a SQL-injection hole!, change the offending line like so: `$sql =("SELECT * FROM products where products.CAT_ID = '$id' AND DISABLED ='NO'");` note the extra single `'` quotes. They are essential!

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I would do:

```
 function getProducts($id)
 {
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM products where products.CAT_ID = ' . $id . ' AND DISABLED = "NO"';
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    if($result !== false) {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            $products[]= $row;
        }
    } else {
        $products = false;
    }
}
```

Then you can print it out via:

```
if($products = getData(id)) {
   foreach($products as $product) {
      echo $product['database_field_name'];
   }
}
```

To see them all for debugging purposes, you can use this:

```
echo '<pre>' . print_r($products, true) . '</pre>';
```

Also, you have to sanitize `$id` somewhere using:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php and perhaps use `intval()` if it's an integer.

Store data in session:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['name'] = $product['database_field_name'];
```

And then on the insert.php page you can read the data via:

```
echo $_SESSION['name'];
```

Then after you don't need it anymore, you can unset it:

```
unset($_SESSION['name']);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Ryan..

I was already able to print out the $product, through and echo... The issue I am having is, I have one php file, that queries a MySQL table to get me $product array that is displayed in php/html form. This is all working fine.. 

I can't figure out how to get this $products array to insert into a different MySQL table on submit.

Comment: @Jessica Villanueva you have to build an INSERT statement using the data found in $_POST.

Comment: @Jessica Villanueva there are a few ways to debug this. 1. I'd print out all of the `$_POST` data via `print_r($_POST)` to make sure you have all the data you expect. 2. I would echo the SQL statement to make sure it's valid... you can even run it in something like phpMyAdmin to ensure it works. 3. You can use the `mysql_error()` function to echo out any MySQL errors. Last but not least, you should never use `$_POST` directly in SQL statement without escaping it, regardless of whether you think it might be safe to use or not.

Comment: @Jessica Villanueva you wouldn't usually directly insert a name into a new table, you'd reference it with a foreign key, because names generally change, but keys do not. You could have a hidden input field and store the value there, but that's not really a good practice as it can be manipulated. The same goes for having the name in the URL. So the only other way to get it is via a query using that items ID number. If you already have the name stored in a variables, you can just use the variable.

Comment: @Ryan, how would i get the ID to insert?

Comment: @Jessica Villanueva change your form's action from `insert.php` to something like `insert.php?id= . $id` where `$id` is the id of the name. Then on the insert page you need to validate it (make sure it exists) and get the name via that. Or, you could store the name in a `$_SESSION` and then on the insert page check the `$_SESSION` for the name, provided that both pages (form and insert) are on the same server.

Comment: @Ryan S. both my files are stored on the same server.. Do you mind providing example?

Comment: @Jessica Villanueva check my answer, I added how to store the data in a session.